# Difference between handlerUpstream and sendUpstream in netty

Tags: netty, nio

I am new to NIO and Netty framework.

I am developing the sample HTTP server using netty so I can handle thousands of clients connection asynchronously. I have used multiple handlers for encoding, decoding, aggregating and many.

When message received event occurred at one handler, then I pass it to next handler and so on.

For passing an even I have used `ctx.sendUpstream(e) //ctx-ChannelHandlerContext, e-event`

But going through the source code of the netty, I came across the another method `handleUpstream(ctx, e)`

I have tried to debug the netty source code, I am really confused between the usage of the `sendUpstream()` and `handleUpstream()`.

How they differ from each other?Which one I should use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right, Netty 3 uses `ChannelUpstreamHandler.handleUpstream()` to process incoming messages and `ctx.sendUpstream()` to pass messages further upstream. Netty 4 has other methods like `ctx.fireChannelRead()`

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Let's say handler1 on the event messageReceived process on that data and wants to pass it to handler2 using sendUpstream(). Then handler2 also process that data in messageReceived() event only. So Do I need to process data in handleUpstream() method instead of messageRecieved() in handler2 ?

Comment: It depends on handlers and adapters you are using.
Base interface ChannelUpstreamHandler has single method handleUpstream() (no messageReceved()). So, if you implement this interface you should use handleUpstream().
If you are using adapter like SingleChannelHandler you should process messages in messageReceived()

Comment: You mean to say, if I implement the ChannelUpstreamHandler() then I should override handleUpstream() method, and If I extends SimpleChannelUpstreamhandler then I should use messageReceived().   But my question is, If I implement ChannelUpstreamhandler() then how Can I handle channelConnected() channelDisconnected() events as there is only one method handleUpstream() in the interface?

Comment: Netty's sink sends upstream messages to notify about channel state changes - ChannelStateEvent.
SimpleChannelUpstreamHandler processes these messages as following:

Comment: if (e instanceof ChannelStateEvent) {
            ChannelStateEvent evt = (ChannelStateEvent) e;
            switch (evt.getState()) {
            case CONNECTED:
                if (evt.getValue() != null) {
                    channelConnected(ctx, evt);
                } else {
                    channelDisconnected(ctx, evt);
                }
                break;
   ...
            }